# How can I hide the style side panel in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

Is it possible to hide the style side panel in Firebug? For most of my Firebug usage, I don't need this side panel so I'd like to be able to hide it to reclaim some horizontal space.

If it's useful to know, I'm running Firebug 1.11.2 on Firefox 20.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Though there is already an [enhancement request for this in Firebug's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6095).

Though you can resize the panels to minimize them by dragging the separator between the main and the side panels to the right.

Sebastian